# Add Monogame View to Xamarin Storyboard for iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, monogame

I'm very used to working with Monogame but am just getting started in Xamarin. I have created a Xamarion iOS project with a storyboard (seen in picture). This works and I have created Segues and web service calls and what not that work great.

Now to the question. 
How do I add a Monogame view to this? 
Ideally I would like to add a Monogame view to the same storyboard that I can just switch to like I do all the Views. I have however not been able to find any guides or hints on how to do this. The guides I have found so far either speak of storyboards or a Monogame app, not how to use them together.

[image]

**Update**: Any answer that shows how to start a Monogame instance while in the regular storyboard mode programatically and exit back into the storyboard menues is acceptable. It does not have to be a subview, I'm fine with if it takes the whole screen.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer this question in a better way than [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23526048/5416) ... but to summarize, you probably want to let MonoGame "run" the application for you, and when you want to use UIKit, you'd basically either push a custom controller onto the stack, or show a new `UIView` on top of the existing monogame screen.

> Sadly, you will have to modify how MonoGame works if you want to show your MonoGame game after a UIKit controller.